# Capture of packets with tcpdump delayed for seconds until next invocation

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I am maintaining a hardware test suite for a 40G network device, and many of our tests consist of sending handcrafted UDP packets from a test host via `tcpreplay` to our DUT and back to the test host, where we capture the packets with `tcpdump` and process the output.

The test host is equipped with Intel XL710 NICs, running Linux 5.4.0 with the `i40e` driver and the setup looks something like this:

```
************       **********       *******
|       th0> ----- >sw0  sw1> ----- >dut0 |
| Testhost |       | Switch |       | DUT |
|       th1< ----- <sw3  sw2< ----- <dut1 |
************       **********       *******
```

Our problem is that the last few (<10) packets sent from `th0` during one test eratically don't show up in the `tcpdump` output on `th1`, which runs for several seconds after the last packet has been sent.  We have made sure that in such cases the packets have already left `sw3` while `tcpdump` is running by observing the queue counters on the switch and can thus rule out the DUT being at fault. There are no packets listed as being dropped by the kernel by `tcpdump`, and the missing packets always show up during a subsequent invocation of `tcpdump` during the next test, where they are not expected, but only after more packets have been sent over the link.

Executing `tcpdump` with the `--immediate-mode` flag does not help. The missing packets also do not show up in the `rx_packets` counter output from `ethtool -S th1`.

I am not even entirely sure how to interpret all this, but my best guess would be that these packets are somehow being buffered by either the NIC or the Linux networking stack and not flushed out until more packets are arriving. I would be grateful for any hints on what might be going on, what else I can do to debug this problem, or how to work around it.

Comment: Is your NIC doing "interrupt coalescing", or any form of receive offloading? I'd start disabling things like that to see if it makes a difference. It might yield a clue. Or try a different brand of NIC.

Comment: @Spiff thank you, yes, i have started looking into interrupt coalescing and also considered it as a possible culprit. the `rx-frames-irq` parameter is set to 256 and can not be modified via `ethtool`, by my understanding meaning if an interrupt is triggered while another is still being processed, that interrupt may be delayed for up to 255 frames. unfortunately, replacing the NIC is not an option for the moment. are there any performance tweaks i could try to speed up the interrupt processing?